# "Unresolved external symbol public _thiscall" linker error calling constructor and destructor

Tags: linker

This may seem a duplicate. Instead, I've tried to find a similar post of my issue on StackOverflow but I can't resolve the linker error.

These are the linker errors:

**1.**

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ged::Mathematichs::GFraction::~GFraction(void)" (??1GFraction@Mathematichs@ged@@QAE@XZ)

**and 2.**

> LNK2001   unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ged::Mathematichs::GFraction::GFraction(int,int)" (??0GFraction@Mathematichs@ged@@QAE@HH@Z)

I've linked this project to my static library (where GFraction is defined).
**The problem isn't the linking to the library**, because I've other classes in that lib that actually work.

This is the definition of the constructor and destructor

```
#ifndef GFraction_H
#define GFraction_H
#include <string>

namespace ged
{
   namespace Mathematichs
   {
      class GFraction
      {
      public:
          GFraction();
          GFraction(int num, int den);
      };
    }
  }
  #endif
```

In the .cpp file I have this:

```
#include "GFraction.h"

using namespace ged::Mathematichs;

GFraction::GFraction() {}
GFraction::~GFraction() {}
```

But, if I try to implement the body of the costructors and of the destructor direcly in the .h files, the linker errors goes away.

Why? I want those to be in the .cpp file!

Comment: where's numerator and denomatior from the GFraction class?

Comment: @val they're private variables. I didn't write them here not to make that confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.cpp` file the `using`-directive:

```
using namespace ged::Mathematichs;
```

imports into the global namespace any definitions that already exist
in namespace `ged::Mathematichs`. It does not *add* any new definitions
to that namespace. In particular it does not add the definitions:

```
GFraction::GFraction() {}
GFraction::~GFraction() {}
```

to that namespace, where as the linker tells you, they need to be. They
remain in the global namespace. Write your header file like this:

```
#ifndef GFraction_H
#define GFraction_H
#include <string>

namespace ged
{
    namespace Mathematichs
    {
        class GFraction
        {
        public:
            GFraction();
            ~GFraction(); // <- You need to declare the destructor
            GFraction(int num, int den);
        };
    }
}
```

And your  `.cpp` file like this:

```
#include "GFraction.h"

namespace ged {
namespace Mathematichs {

GFraction::GFraction() {}
GFraction::~GFraction() {}
GFraction(int num, int den) { ... }

} // namespace Mathematichs
} // namespace ged
```

to put the definitions in the same namespaces as the declarations.

Comment: In the .cpp he uses the using-directive of the namespace that contains the class. I want to achieve that too

Comment: I am not guessing: I am telling you what is wrong with your code.
It is also wrong with the `Array.cpp` you have linked to ( which
I am afraid is rubbish).

Comment: I made the .cpp as you suggested, but I get these errors: http://prntscr.com/9na25y

Comment: @Michele According to the code and the linker diagnostics you have posted already, class `GFraction` is within namespace
`ged::Mathematichs`, but in this `.cpp` file you are
placing the definitions in namespace `ged::Mathematics`